# converting value GB to TB in awk function

Tags: awk

we are trying to convert the value in GB to TB, is there anything missing in my code.

Sample output

```
isi status -q | grep -e "^Size" -e "^Used" -e "^Avail"
Size:       501T (5041T Raw)    19T (19T Raw)
Used:       440G (80%)          1.4T(7%)
Avail:      61T (12%)           18T (93%)
```

**Require Output** In Some cases `Used` value can be in GB need to convert it into TB

```
Size:       501T 
Used:       0.39T
Avail:      61T
```

I tried this but not getting the expected result

```
isi status -q | grep -e "^Size" -e "^Used" -e "^Avail" | awk '{print $1 $2}' | awk 'function num2gb(n) { if (n ~ /T$/) return n / 1; return n / 14; }
/Size:/ { size=$NF }
/Used:/ { used=num2gb($NF) }
END {
print size
print "used=" used }'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your arithmetic, but perhaps something like

```
awk '/^(Size|Used|Avail):/ {
  $2 = $2 ~ /G$/ ? sprintf("%.2fT", ($2+0)/1024) : $2;
  print $1, $2;
}' OFS='\t' file
```